# ERROR: Permission to denied to

Tags: git, github, ssh

When I try to push my repository to Github I'm getting the following

[image]

The thing is that I have two accounts on Github and I am using SSH key for the second one. I intended to use first account for some test repositories or my experimental ideas. And now I can't push there my project.

Comment: you can simply add the same public key to both of the github accounts to get rid of this problem.

Comment: adding as an answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add the same public key to both of the github accounts to get rid of this problem.